# Trouble turning comorbidity data into a table using Python and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, kaggle, chord-diagram

I'm trying to analyze the occurrence of comorbidity from a Kaggle dataset as a geeky training exercise. I've been able to get all the fifteen morbidities from the dataset. However, at this point I struggle to turn this into a dataframe or the likes.

My thoughts at this point are focused on creating a 15 x 15 table using the list of morbidities. Which I would like to use to create a radial convergence diagram. However, I'm at a loss how to fill this table (or if this is even the correct approach...).

Is someone able to give me a push in the right direction either regarding coding or name of this table type?

Original Kaggle; https://www.kaggle.com/nih-chest-xrays/data/kernels

My script thusfar;

```
#Load data
df = pd.read_csv("Data_Entry_2017.csv")

#Filter data
df_filtered = df.iloc[:, 1:6]
df_filtered = df_filtered.drop(df_filtered.columns[[1,2]],axis=1)


#List findings
df_string = df_filtered['Finding Labels']
df_string.str.strip()

findings = []

for finding in df_string:
    finding = finding.split('|')
    for findingX in finding:
        findings.append(findingX)
findingsSolo = list(set(findings))

#df from findings list
df_findings = pd.DataFrame(columns=findingsSolo, index=findingsSolo)
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who come across my question, after some brooding I came up with a solution;

```
df_findings = pd.DataFrame(columns=findings, index=findings).fillna(0)

for finding in df_string:
    finding = finding.split('|')
    finding.sort()
    if len(finding) > 1:
        col_label = finding[0]
        for row_label in finding[1::]:
            df_findings.loc[row_label,col_label] += 1
```